# Is every monotonic function on $[a, b]$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Is every monotonic function on $[a, b]$ bounded?

My thought is, YES 
But in case of $f (x)=1/x$ on $[0,1]$ which is monotonically decreasing on domain of definition $(0,1]$ but which is not monotonic at $x=0$ 
because a monotonic function can have only jump discontinuity but at $0$ $f(x)=1/x$ has mixed discontinuity or discontinuity of second kind

Is my answer is correct?

Comment: Every monotonic function on $[a, b]$ is bounded by $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

Comment: No – again, $1/x$ is **not defined** at 0; your function $f$ is defined only on $(0, 1]$. We're dealing with *real-valued functions*, not extended-real-valued functions (otherwise it's silly or trivial to talk about boundedness). How can I say this clearly enough? – **$f$ is not a function on $[0, 1]$**.

Comment: Your example isn't a good one because you are asking about the statement "every monotonic function with domain $[a,b]$ is bounded", but you didn't exhibit a monotonic function on $[0,1]$.  You exhibited a monotonic function on $(0,1]$, as you pointed out, so your example cannot be applied to the original statement.  ($1/x$ is not monotonic on $[0,1]$ because $[0,1]$ isn't its domain.)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is non-decreasing then $f(a)\leq f(x)\leq f(b)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.If $f$ is non-increasing then $f(b)\leq f(x)\leq f(a)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.So $f$ is bounded above by $\max(f(a),f(b))$ and bounded  below by $\min (f(a),f(b))$.

Comment: Typos: "If ff is non-increasing then f(b)≤f(x)≤f(a) for all **a∈[a,b[**" -- should be "$x \in [a, b]$".

Comment: ok fixed it. BTW  Bourbaki uses "increasing " to mean "non-decreasing" and vice versa.

Comment: I used to, too. "increasing" and "strictly increasing". I worked through quite a bit of Bourbaki but I didn't get it from him/them/there. It always seemed to me weird usage to call a function "non-decreasing" which everywhere increases or is flat. Like "don't think of a pink elephant", you *do* think of "decrease", even if only for a few milliseconds. Funny you should mention Bourbaki - I thought of them when I noticed you'd written "[a, b[" :)

Comment: PS Not to rant, but "non-{de|in}creasing" is sorta lousy terminology: sin(x) is "non-decreasing" - sure isn't decreasing! as well as "non-increasing".You always have to preface those terms with "monotone" to indicate order preserving or reversing. Why not/how about "increasing or equal"? by analogy with "≤". Then unqualified "increasing" can then mean "strictly", which is current usage anyway... cf. "<". Similarly for the other direction.

Comment: that  is probably why Bourbaki and others dropped it. good point.